# Creating a child record using with a form pre filled with parent, without changing route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Makes model:

```
class Make < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :models, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :trims, :through => :models
end
```

and a Model model:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :year, :make_id, :trim_id
  belongs_to :make
  has_many :trims
  validates :make_id, presence: true  
end
```

Now ignoring my mass assignment vulnerability for a second, how do I accomplish something like this: Once a Make is created via /makes/new and returned to makes/1, presented with a page containing a link to create a model using that Make.

I know I can define another controller to do this and prefill the `make_id` field, but is this the correct way? My route for creating Models is `/models/new`. Is there a way to prefill that form, AND let it act as if it's not prefilled?

Answer (score 1):

One surefire way to do this would be to create a dynamic route to model/new/:make_id.

In the "link to create a model using that Make" on your make#show page, set it up to use your new route.

Then, in the model controller's new action, assign it to its own instance variable:

```
@make_id = params[:make_id]
```

In model#new's view, you can populate the form's make text_field (assuming it's a text_field) with that variable:

```
<%= f.text_field :make, :value => @make_id %>
```

If you want to be more elaborate, you can use @make_id in your view to hide the textfield and set a hidden input if @make.present?. Since anyone can mess with that page by fiddling with the URL, I suggest validating that the make_id passed in is valid.

Comment: Ahh so the route model/new/:make_id is just a helper route with the controller using the proper model.new controller?

Comment: Correct. You can achieve the same effect by adding a URL variable (a la model/new?make=3) to your model/new path, but using a route is more rails-like.